# How would I make a website available ONLY during a set time-period (6 months of the year)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I am currently designing a website with a login system connected to a database.

I am planning to code most of it using HTML, CSS and JavaScript.

What I was wondering is simply whether it is possible to only allow users to access the website, for example 6 months of the year or between 2 set dates, and the rest of the time if they try to access the website they'll simply be directed to a page which says something like 'sorry page not available at the moment, please come back in ___'?

Comment: yes this is doable. There are many different approaches you can use. `.htaccess` simple `if/else` ...

Answer (score 0):

Just go with a date check and do a redirect, if necessary:

```php
<?php
$date_current = new DateTime();
$date_limit = new DateTime("01/01/2021");

if ( $date_current > $date_limit ) {
    header("Location: https://mysite/unavailable.php");
    die();
}
```

Replace `https://mysite/unavailable.php` with the page with your warning.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible.
You can use the Date and code something like this: if DateToday >= StartDate || DateToday < EndDate { change document.location to target url}

Comment: Appreciate it:)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with rewrite rule using a .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{TIME_MON} >6
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.yourwebsite.com/specialsite.html
```

The rewirte conditions available for the current date:

```
TIME_YEAR // four-digit year
TIME_MON // month
TIME_DAY // day of month
TIME_HOUR // hour (24 hour clock) of day
TIME_MIN // minute of hour
TIME_SEC // second of minute
TIME_WDAY // week-day

TIME // a formatted string representing the date and time down to seconds. e.g. 20150827112234
```

Additional the condition for a specific year would be:

```
RewriteCond %{TIME_YEAR}%{TIME_MON} <202006
```

It is also possible to combine conditions (RewriteConds are inclusive like a logical AND) by chaining them and using [OR].

```
RewriteCond %{TIME_YEAR} > 2016  
RewriteCond %{TIME_MON} < 04 [OR]
RewriteCond %{TIME_MON} > 07
```

But be aware that here [OR] has a higher precedence than "AND". The example above results in:

```
%{TIME_YEAR} > 2016 && (%{TIME_MON} < 04 || %{TIME_MON} > 07)
```

for your example I would split this in two:

```
RewriteCond %{TIME_MON}%{TIME_DAY} >= 0301  
RewriteCond %{TIME_MON}%{TIME_DAY} <= 0307 

RewriteCond %{TIME_MON}%{TIME_DAY} >= 1001
RewriteCond %{TIME_MON}%{TIME_DAY} <= 1007
```

Comment: Thank you! I will then merely use this and create a loop so it'll be available suring a couple months of the year. Appreciate it

Comment: I could also set the condition to !=, so that when the time condition is not within say March 1st-7th, nor October 1st-7th, it will redirect the user to another page? Say something like: %{TIME_MON}%{TIME_DAY} >= 0301 && %{TIME_MON}%{TIME_DAY} <=0307 || %{TIME_MON}%{TIME_DAY} >= 1001 && %{TIME_MON}%{TIME_DAY} <= 1007 (splitting it into 2 conditions)?

Comment: updated the answer with respect to your question